# Not able to set the text label when using modal segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, ios6.0

I am new to iOS development. 
I am using storyboards and whenever I use modal segue to come back to previous screen by

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];`

I get the correct animation on clicking the Table View Controller but I don't get the proper data whatever i have set to the object. It prints on the the console but if I use that to set the label it does not set even if I put that in another string it is not able to set the label.

If I am doing the same thing with the help of push segue it is working fine but not able to pop out of stack to show the previous screen.

So my questions are:

- Why the label is not setting even if string is printing on output console when I am using the modal segue?
- How can I get the pop out animation when I am using the push segue for this?

Comment: Which label?! Try to explain better.

Comment: Please show some code.