# Not able to set a Label on a view by using model segue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, storyboard, segue

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaNjH.png]

[problem StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaNjH.png)

I want to use the model segue. By clicking on 'Year' button it should go to the 'Year View Controller' click on the table cell and screen is set to initial view controller set the Label 1 in the view controller.

**Person.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CarObj : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *Year;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString* Name;

@end
```

After that click on the Name button it should go to the Name View Controller and on click it should save the info of cell to the 'Name' parameter of Person.h.

How to implement this? I am not able to set the Label 1 and Label 2....

for segue I am using :

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GrabYear"])
{
YearViewController *yvc = [segue destinationViewController];
[yvc setCurrentCar:currentCar];
}
}
```

and for the row selection I am using:

```
MenuViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuSB"];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
CarObj *c = [cars objectAtIndex:[path row]];
[mvc setCurrentCar:c];

[mvc viewDidLoad]; // I am not getting previous view loaded automatically
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

the string which I am getting in currentCar.year is not able to set the Label by using
[yearLabel setText:currentCar.year];

Comment: A note for the future, you should have updated your previous question (please delete it to keep things tidy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359330/not-able-to-set-the-text-label-when-using-modal-segue)

Comment: Using delegation? Show the code where you handle the segue and the table cell selection.

Comment: Why are you using modal segues instead of push segues?

Comment: Have a look at Ray Wenderlich's excellent iOS Storyboarding tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Answer (score 3):

The controller's call to [controller view] has not happened in the api's chain of events.
Hence, any value you set on the view's sub controls without first loading child controls, will be overwritten, leaving you befuddled with the mystery.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
    id vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    MyController *controller = (MyController*)vc;

    //You'll need lazy load controller child controls "now"! with this method call
    [controller view];

    //now you can set controls 
    controller.myLabel.text = @"Value will now persist";

    //note objects not owned by the "view" can be set here without the hack
   controller.myContextSting = @"This value will persist without the hack";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is this code:

```
MenuViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuSB"];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
CarObj *c = [cars objectAtIndex:[path row]];
[mvc setCurrentCar:c];

[mvc viewDidLoad]; // I am not getting previous view loaded automatically
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Because you are creating a new instance of your `MenuViewController`, configuring it and then throwing it away.

What you want to do is add a delegate property to the year and name view controllers and have your `MenuViewController` set itself as the delegate in `prepareForSegue:`. Then, on row selection you would do something like:

```
[self.delegate setCurrentCar:c];
```

Instead of what you're currently doing with `mvc`.